# Huber-White robust standard errors for a GLMM - R

Tags: r, mixed-models, standard-error

I have discovered some heteroscedasticity in my model that I would like to compensate for with more robust standard errors. I have tried to use the Huber-White robust standard errors from the `merDeriv` package in R but I beleive these only work for a GLMM with a binomial distribution. Is there a way I could achieve the same thing for a Negative Binomial distribition?

Model:

```
library(lme4)
model <- glmer.nb(Jobs ~ 1 + Month + Year + (1|Region), data = df)
```

Huber-White robust standard errors:

```
library(merDeriv)
bread.glmerMod(model)
```

Error:

```
Error in vcov.lmerMod(object, full = full) : estfun.lmerMod() only works for lmer() models.
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the package, as far as I can tell (the `bread.glmerMod` function was calling `estfun.lmerMod` rather than `estfun.glmerMod`; there's a broader question here about the design of the generic functions, but never mind ...)

You should be able to install a fixed version from my fork via `remotes::install_github("bbolker/merDeriv")`, then reload the package and try again.

Alternately, download the tarball, change `vcov.lmerMod` to `vcov.glmerMod` in the last line of `R/bread.glmerMod.R`, and re-install the package ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
library(lme4)
model <- glmer.nb(Jobs ~ 1 + Month + Year + (1|Region), data = df)

cov <- vcovHC(model, type = "HC1", sandwich = T)
se <- sqrt(diag(cov_m1))
```

(Can't confirm if it works since this there isn't a reproducible example)

Comment: doesn't actually work, I think (although sort of the OP's fault for not providing a [mcve] ...)